# cuda fortran speed-up

Tags: cuda, fortran

I am trying to evaluate the speed-up of a simple cuda fortran code: increment of an array.

CPU version:

```
module simpleOps_m
contains
subroutine increment (a, b)
implicit none
integer , intent ( inout ) :: a(:)
integer , intent (in) :: b
integer :: i, n

n = size (a)
do i = 1, n
a(i) = a(i)+b
enddo

end subroutine increment
end module simpleOps_m


program incrementTest
use simpleOps_m
implicit none
integer , parameter :: n = 1024*1024*100
integer :: a(n), b

a = 1
b = 3


call increment (a, b)


if ( any(a /= 4)) then
write (* ,*) '**** Program Failed **** '
else
write (* ,*) 'Program Passed '
endif
end program incrementTest
```

GPU version:

```
module simpleOps_m
contains
attributes ( global ) subroutine increment (a, b)
implicit none
integer , intent ( inout ) :: a(:)
integer , value :: b
integer :: i, n

n = size (a)

do i=blockDim %x*( blockIdx %x -1) + threadIdx %x ,n, BlockDim %x* GridDim %x
    a(i) = a(i)+b
end do

end subroutine increment
end module simpleOps_m

program incrementTest
use cudafor
use simpleOps_m
implicit none
integer , parameter :: n = 1024*1024*100
integer :: a(n), b
integer , device :: a_d(n)
integer :: tPB = 256

a = 1
b = 3

a_d = a
call increment <<< 128,tPB >>>(a_d , b)
a = a_d

if ( any(a /= 4)) then
write (* ,*) '**** Program Failed **** '
else
write (* ,*) 'Program Passed '
endif
end program incrementTest
```

So I compile both versions with pgf90
http://www.pgroup.com/resources/cudafortran.htm

Using "time" command to evaluate execution time, I obtain:

---

for CPU version

$ time (cpu executable)

real    0m0.715s

user    0m0.410s

sys 0m0.300s

---

for GPU version

$ time (gpu executable)

real    0m1.057s

user    0m0.710s

sys    0m0.340s

---

So the speed-up=(CPU exec.time)/(GPU exec.time) is < 1
Are there some reason why the speed-up is not > 1 as one should attain?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't comment on this in any detail, I haven't read your code and have no experience of CUDA Fortran.  But in general, I wouldn't form any conclusions on speed-up based on the run time of one job which takes about 1s. It wouldn't surprise me to learn that moving data to and from the GPU's local memory takes more time than computation on the GPU saves in a relatively short job.

Comment: Exactly, even without the memory trasfers, acquiring of the GPU and allocation takes some time.

Comment: When benchmarking CUDA or OpenCL code there should be a first "warm-up" kernel execution so that all contexts could be properly acquired and initialised before the actual benchmarking process starts so not to interfere with the timing. Still, there is a certain computation to volume of memory transfers ratio that if not met would lead to poor performance.

Comment: I would profile you host CPU version - I suspect that `a=3` might be taking as much  of the total execution time that the actual vector addition. Ahmdahl's law will start to work against you pretty fast in that case....

Comment: +1 to @talonmies comment -- a quick gprof points out that the a=1 line takes ~32% of the time, with the increment operation only taking ~44% of the time.  So even without memory copy overhead, etc, the available speedup is very modest for this simple program.

Comment: Many thanks to talonmies and Jonathan, you're right!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that in this rather contrived example, the cost of initialising the large array on the host (`a=1`) is almost the same as the cost of loop to increment the array contents, which is the part of the code being parallelised on the GPU. Because the total amount of parallel work is about the same as the total amount of serial work, [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) is heavily stacked against achieving any sort of significant speed up by parallelising some of the code on the GPU.

A more significant speed up could probably be achieved by fusing the initialisation and increment operations into a single parallel operation on the GPU.

[This answer has been assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get this question off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag]